# jquery append and attr.appendTo

Tags: jquery, appendto

Why this code works:

```
$(this).append($(this).parent().find("div:not(.exit_block)").attr("id"));
```

and this not:

```
$(this).parent().find("div:not(.exit_block)").attr("id").appendTo($(this));
```

? Debugger writes that appendTo is not a function. How must I use appendTo in this situation? I want to append attribute id to content in $(this) using appendTo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second line doesn't work because you're trying to call `.appendTo` on a value, not on a jQuery object.

[`.attr docs`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

> Description: Get the value of an attribute for the first element in
>   the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to call the `appendTo()` method on the return value of `attr()`, which returns an attribute value. I believe, from looking at your code, that you want to append to the div.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are trying to appendTo to an attr.

```
$(this).parent().find("div:not(.exit_block)").attr("id").appendTo($(this));
```

Are you trying to do this??

```
$("#"+$(this).parent().find("div:not(.exit_block)").attr("id")).appendTo($(this));
```

Comment: Op wants to append the attribute value and not the element with that id

Comment: He doesn't state that.  I suggested a solution based on his line.  Why would you "-1" that?

Comment: First, he's using appendTo, not append.  Second, the first line looks as though he's trying to append the id text to an element.  The second line looks like he's trying to "appendTo", or move, an entire element to another element.  That's why I wrote it that way.  So, please remove the -1 since I was correcting his logic that was provided since the Op didn't state his objection.

Comment: @overhernow.. Tried removing it .. But says vote locked .. Sorry :)